# Is there a text to speech software that allows you to save the audio for later?

Tags: pdf, okular, text-to-speech, word-documents

So, basically I'm looking for a text-to-speech software that not only can read my files to me (I currently use Okular), but also would let me save the speech as an audio file, so that I can listen to it another time somewhere else.

And, obviously, if Okular already has this feature I'd like to know how to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with **Espeak** from the repository.

The command options are simple (`man espeak`).  You can pipe text through espeak or use the `-f <text file>` option to have it speak a text file.

The normal output is the audio sound.  Use the option `--standout > filename.wav` to **save the output to an audio for later**.

These steps will create a file, `hello.wav`.  The first line will create the file.  The second line will play the file.

```
$ echo "Hello, I am a computer." | espeak --stdout > hello.wav
$ mplayer hello.wav
```

This will create a wav file of a text file.  The second line will play the text file.

```
$ espeak -f readme.txt --stdout > readme.wav
$ mplayer readme.wav
```

**Note:**

You can turn a PDF file into a text file with `pdftotext`, then process the text file with the steps above.

Comment: HAve you tried this with pdfs Orkular is a GUI pdf reader. This will not work with a pdf file which is what the question is about.

Comment: The user specified his files.  I didn't infer that he was speaking of PDF files.  I'm not familiar with Orkular.  Thought his reference was just a mention of what he's using if that would work.  As far a PDF files, they can easily be turned into text files and processed using the step I mentioned above, for creating sound files out of text files.    I ran a pdf through `pdftotext` and processed the text file with the steps above and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @ianorlin I just installed Okular.  It has an export to text feature.  So this could be used to export the file into text, then process the text via the steps above.